# Manipulation events in a ListBox in wpf4 is never raised

Tags: wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a ListBox control defined within MainWindow and its IsManipulationEnabled property is set to true. I have the manipulation events (OnManipulationStarting, OnManipulationInertiaStarting and OnManipulationDelta) defined in the MainWindow. The goal here is to achieve a translation on the Listbox control, more like a flip functionality.

However, these events are never raised. I am assuming that the selection events are in turn gobbling these events. When I use itemscontrol instead, it works fine. But the problem in using itemscontrol is that I do not get a selection state. Another option would be to work on raw touch, but manipulations are way easier.

Why do the Manipulation events not fire on Listbox?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The default template for an **ItemsControl** doesn't contain a ScrollViewer but the ListBox does. The **ScrollViewer** handles those events when the PanningMode is something other than None. By default a ScrollViewer binds several of its properties (like PanningMode) to that of its templated parent. Try setting the attached **ScrollViewer.PanningMode** property to **None** on the ListBox.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.PanningMode="None" />
```

Comment: And what if I want panning? :p

Comment: You want the scrollviewer to pan and still get the manipulation events at a higher element? Well then maybe you would hook the events using AddHandler and passing in true for getting Handled events. Or maybe hook the events on an element within the scrollviewer instead.